# Testing the max() functions in SQL (Teradata) without having to query a database

Tags: sql, max, teradata

This is probably a simple one, but I'm not able to find it anywhere. I just want to check what the MAX() function in a Teradata SQL query would return, using a list of strings. I have a Teradata database I'm working with, but I don't have a table to query (I need to know the output of MAX() before I can populate the table data). I'm using Aqua Data Studio.

I tried

```
select max('test1','untest2','_test3')
```

and I also tried

```
select max(field_name) where field_name in ('test1','untest2','_test3')
```

but both throw an error.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know Teradata but `max()` is an aggregate function and doesn't do what it looks like you think it might - aggregate functions work with a *set of rows*

Comment: `select GREATEST('test1','untest2','_test3')` works on multiple *columns* instead of multiple *rows*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that be the [GREATEST](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/xjMvblfYmLcRgqniGyznLw) function instead?

```
select greatest('test1','untest2','_test3')
```

Comment: Thanks! Would max() over rows behave the same way as greatest()? I eventually have to take it to row aggregation.

Comment: You're welcome. MAX returns the largest value within a single column (through many rows). If that's what you're looking for, then yes - it would do the job. Otherwise, it's the GREATEST. Choose a function that suits you most.

Comment: Caution: Both MAX and GREATEST on strings depend on collation and casespecific settings.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
select max(field_name)
from
(
    select 'test1' as field_name union
    select 'untest2' as field_name union
    select '_test3' as field_name
) tbl
```

Comment: Throws an error. Maybe it's a Teradata thing.

Comment: Teradata requires a from clause in unions.

Answer (score 0):

try providing data via VALUES or UNNEST(array)

```sql
SELECT max(x) FROM (
  VALUES ('test1'),('untest2'),('_test3')
) AS x(x)
```

or

```sql
SELECT max(x) FROM 
  UNNEST(ARRAY['test1','untest2','_test3']) AS x
```

Comment: Teradata does not support VALUES syntax, and ARRAYs require a User-Defined Type declaration.